# How to make a view to cover another view in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My website is split in a navbar and left,center and right pane.

In the center pane I usually render a view (using Ractivejs).

Occasionally I need to render a view that is bigger than the center pane and I want it to render for the full 100% width but when I unrender it for the previous panes to be visible.

I tried to do it by resizing on the fly the centerPane with from col-md-4 to col-md-12 but bootstrap moves it to a new line.

I do not want to include logic for re-rendering the left and right pane, I want to cover them so they are always rendered.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="leftPane"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="centerPane"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="rightPane"></div>
</div>
```

*I want centerPane to overlap the other two divs (left,right) with some code. Or to create a new element that will hide all of the three and when it is removed from the DOM they are shown.*

Comment: use fixed position and z-index for managing layers.

Comment: You can show your view in popup(jQuery). @arisalexis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an element to overlay all other elements, you could add a class to it that has a fixed position:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 101; // Change as needed
}
```

#### [Here is a simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/wg6pon50/)